# Use an existing lambda function as datasource in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I'm trying to use an existing Lambda function as a data source and create an EC2 instance. This Lambda function essentially provides the latest AMI.

I'm looking at this doc:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_invocation

**Source Block**:

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "example" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.resource_selector.ResourceSelector
  input = <<JSON
{
  "key1": "AMIRegexPattern"
  
  }
JSON
}

output "result_entry" {
  value = jsondecode(data.aws_lambda_invocation.example.result)["key1"]
}
```

It throws this **error** and I'm a little lost:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on create-ec2.tf line 26, in data "aws_lambda_invocation" "example":
  26:   function_name = aws_lambda_function.resource_selector.ResourceSelector

A managed resource "aws_lambda_function" "resource_selector" has not been
declared in the root module.
```

Here is the function details:

```
Function Name - ResourceSelector
Function ARN : arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xx50:function:ResourceSelector
```

Any help on what I am missing? Also curious on this line esp and if this is correct:

```
function_name = aws_lambda_function.resource_selector.ResourceSelector
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lambda is created outside terraform you have to hardcode or pass via parameter, like so:

```
function_name = "ResourceSelector"
```

`aws_lambda_function.resource_selector` doesn't exist, or you can manage the lambda defininng the [aws_lambda_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function) resource.

Also if you just want to get the latest AMI you don't need a lambda. Terraform actually has a data source that can pull that for you: [aws_ami](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ami)

Example:

```
data "aws_ami" "example" {
  most_recent      = true
  owners           = ["self"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["myami-*"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erico. This was helpful. I had to specify the function name and then it worked. I can't use this aws_ami data source as it's a requirement to use the lambda function to select the latest n greatest ami.